# Cython install problem

Tags: python, windows, installation, cython

I got Cython 0.15 and tried to install it like this

```
python setup.py install
```

I get this:

```
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'Cython.Plex.Scanners' extension
error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

What does this mean? I have Micorsoft Visual Studio 2008 and Windows SDK. Using Windows 7, python 2.6

Comment: run this in a Visual Studio Command Prompt

Comment: I've had mixed results with this on multiple computers.  My current system won't install cython, but I'm running from the VS command prompt and I have the ...10.0\vc folder in my path.

Answer (score 5):

I have no direct answer to your question, but I would strongly recommend to give this [**pre-built Cython package**](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#cython) a try.