# Cython: Update to 0.20

Tags: python-2.7, pip, cython, mingw32

I upgraded cython to 0.20 via `pip install --upgrade cython`. Before it was just working fine. Then I couldn't compile anymore. Then I tried to uninstall an reinstall an got this `Unable to find vcvarsall.bat` error which wasn't there when installing cython 0.19...Come to think about it, 0.19 was installed with python(x, y) installation.

```
C:\>gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/mingw32-xy/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/lto-wrapper.e
xe
Target: mingw32
Configured with: ../gcc-4.5.2/configure --enable-languages=c,c++,ada,fortran,obj
c,obj-c++ --disable-sjlj-exceptions --with-dwarf2 --enable-shared --enable-libgo
mp --disable-win32-registry --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-version-specific-r
untime-libs --disable-werror --build=mingw32 --prefix=/mingw
Thread model: win32
gcc version 4.5.2 (GCC)
C:\>ver

Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
C:\>python
Python 2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:43:36) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win
32
```

I followed the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16980330/1797098), but not luck. Any ideas? Any more info I can provide?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cython install problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255390/cython-install-problem)

Answer (score 1):

Well, I got this working using a prebuild version from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#cython) as recommended by tom pohl [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7257954/1797098)

Answer (score 0):

In this case `pip` tries to compile `cython` with visual studio compiler (hence `vcvarsall.bat` error). To compile extensions for Python 2.7 (32-bit) using visual studio compiler you'll need to have [Visual C++ 2008 Express](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15319069/2419207) installed.

But if one day you discover, that you'd like to build `cython` from source, then check out ["How to use MinGW's gcc compiler when installing Python package using Pip?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5051281/2419207)